# Tor dimension of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. How can I explicitly compute 
$$
Tor_{R}^*(k,k)
$$
over the ring $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. After playing around with it for small $n$ and an unreasonable long time, I think the answer is $Tor_{R}^i(k,k)= k^{\binom{n}{i}}$, but I don't know how to prove it in general.

Comment: Have you tried the Koszul complex? It should give u a concrete free resolution of $k$.

Comment: I agree with Simon. And of course this also supports $\mathrm{Tor}^i(k,k) = k^{\binom{n}{i}}$.

Answer (score 3):

The comment should say enough, but for completeness' sake:

Given a ring $R$ and an element $x\in R$ the complex

$$0\to R\xrightarrow{x}R\to 0$$

is called the Koszul complex $K(x)$ of $R$ with respect to $x$. For $x_1,\cdots, x_n\in R$ the Koszul complex $K(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ is the tensor product of the individual complexes $K(x_i)$ in the category of chain complexes.

If $R=k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ and we choose $x_i=X_i$ for all $i$, the Koszul complex is a free resolution of $k$ as an $R$ module. The rank of the $i^{th}$ term is precisely $\binom ni$.

Tensoring this complex with $k$ gives you a complex with terms $k^\binom{n}{i}$ and trivial differentials.